# ElasticSearch - autocomplete typeahead

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch, typeahead

I have an index of records that were imported via a jdbc river.
I want to add a search box to my form to 'suggest' titles, as a user types.

I have read about [Completion Suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) but can not find an example of this being implemented with a jdbc river. The documentation on the ElasticSearch website seems to suggest that 'suggestions' need to be manually inserted.

Can someone provide me with a simple example on how to implement this for records imported via jdbc?
Does this need to be done with a separate index? Or can I use the same index I imported the data with?